# Agora unity 2018 build issue for Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, agora.io

When i build an agora apk 
I got this

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
F:\Unity_2018.3.f1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "F:\Unity_2018.3.f1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\UNI\Downloads\AMG_FULL_Unity_v2_2_3_20\AMG_FULL_Unity\samples\Hello-Video-Unity-Agora\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle' line: 17
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleOut'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
  >   Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 4.6. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\UNI\Downloads\AMG_FULL_Unity_v2_2_3_20\AMG_FULL_Unity\samples\Hello-Video-Unity-Agora\Temp\gradleOut\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Hi! Could you please add some more details about what you were doing when you got this error, and how to replicate it?

Comment: nothing just simple port for android i got this erroe

Answer (score 1):

**Cause of issue:** If you are using an older version of the plugin (*current version 2.4*), there is an issue with the Gradle file that was included (*was meant for older versions of Unity*). Newer versions of Unity ship with a new version of Gradle which is causing the compile errors where Unity throws an error “Unable to build gradle”.

**To resolve:** Open your file explorer and navigate into the project `Assets > Plugins > Android` and delete the `mainTemplate.gradle` file.

Comment: Asset Store link: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/agora-video-sdk-for-unity-134502

Comment: vivo 9 pro android 8.1crashed .

Comment: Saying it’s crashed and the platform is not very informative.  Can you provide more details? Logs? Anything that can give some insight.

Comment: 2019-05-16 21:30:38.744 6364-6391/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
    Process: io.agora.gaming.video.hello, PID: 6364
    java.lang.Error: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
    Build fingerprint: 'vivo/1851/1851:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/compil02271945:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'

Comment: mail me at hanugamesg@gmail.com

Comment: 2019-05-16 21:30:38.744 6364-6391/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
    Process: io.agora.gaming.video.hello, PID: 6364
    java.lang.Error: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
    Build fingerprint: 'vivo/1851/1851:8.1.0